# dbms sql query for the project

Tags: sql

This is the manuscript table

```
BOOKID  AUTHORID    BOOKNAME            GENRE   NOOFCOPIES  AMOUNT
B105    A102        Diagnosis           Journal     500 10000
B102    A102        The Essence Of Life Fiction     110 11000
B106    A102        Clinical Science    Educational 125 18750
B104    A103        Mind Games          Fiction     200 20000
B100    A102        Sublime             Fiction     100 10000
B101    A105        C Programming       Educational 125 18750
B103    A101        Scribe              Journal     500 10000
B107    A101        Clinical Chemistry  Educational 125 54646
B108    A103        Clinical Chemistry  Educational 125 54646
```

How to write a query to retrieve List of authorid and authorname who has published minimum number of books?

**Excepted output is A105's details...**

Comment: Sounds like homework. [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: select a.authorid,a.authorname from author from author a,manuscripts where authorid in (select min(c) from (select count(AuthorId) from manuscripts group by manuscripts)                                         is this correct ??

Comment: in addition to this how can I find authorname whose work has published for minimum number of times ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How can I get the AuthorId who has published book in all Genre ? Expected output ' A102' Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) key word

```
Select TOP 1 BOOKID,AUTHORID from manuscript ORDER BY NOOFCOPIES ASC
```

Using sub query

SELECT m.AuthorId, a.AuthorName
FROM Author a, Manuscript m
WHERE (a.AuthorID = m.AuthorID) AND (m.Numberofcopies
IN ( SELECT MIN(Numberofcopies) FROM Manuscript));

Comment: in addition to this how can I find authorname whose work has published for minimum number of times ? Thanks in advance